# How to cover unit test for the function with function as parameter using sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm trying to attain the coverage of my function as below.

```
function behaveDiff(obj, 'name',function(){
      obj.xyz.call(obj,'name');
})
```

The test case for this I have written which is working fine, but in my code coverage its showing your `function(){obj.xyz.call(obj,'name')}` not covered.

Is there any way to cover the function parameter in `behaveDiff()` function?.

Comment: share the test, pls

Comment: Your code has syntax error. Please fix it.